# Combine vectors into one number

Tags: r, matrix

Is there a way to join together two vectors and quote the result?

I have two vectors that are produced automatically from my code.

```
orderWA<-c(1,0,1)
orderWS<-c(1,0,0)
```

I know i can combine them by doing

```
c(orderWA,orderWS)
```

or

```
append(orderWA,orderWS)
```

Is there anyway to get them to join together and output this:

```
(1 0 1)(1 0 0)
```

And then is there a way that I can get that to show in one cell in a matrix, lets say that (1 0 1)(1 0 0)=order

```
orderMAT<-matrix(c(Model,order),ncol=2)
colnames(orderMAT)<-c("Model","Order of parameters")
```

so that it outputs something like this

```
Model        Order of parameters
ARIMA        (1 0 1)(1 0 0)
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. What structure are you after? `matrix(list(orderWA, orderWS), ncol = 2)`?

Comment: I want to combine orderWA and orderWS so that it can be quoted as "(orderWA)(orderWS)" to make it look like "(1 0 1)(1 0 0)" which can then be quoted in a table in one cell. as when i do it as normal then each number goes in a seperate cell.

Comment: Can you manually create an object that behaves like you expect it to and show that code--then we can see whether there's an easy way to go from your input to your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can represent the combinations of numbers as a string in the following way.

```
# combine numbers
order_string <- paste(paste0("(", 
                             sapply(list(orderWA, orderWS), 
                                    paste, collapse = " "), 
                             ")"), collapse = "")
# create data frame
data.frame(Model = "ARIMA", 
           "Order of paramaters" = order_string,
           check.names = FALSE)

#   Model Order of paramaters
# 1 ARIMA      (1 0 1)(1 0 0)
```